# How to extend the lifetimes of Strings within functions of traits that require returning &str?

Tags: enums, rust

#### Problem

---

I am trying to implement the  [`std::error::Error`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/error/trait.Error.html) trait on a enum. Some elements of the enum are Enum Variants, and I would like to generate a different error message containing the data from the variant. However with the implementation below the formatted `String` that `Deref` to `&str` don't live long enough.

The general solution is to return a `String`. However, this is not an option here as the returned type must be `&str` as specified by the `Error` trait.

---

#### Example: [Playground link](http://is.gd/aC5WWa)

---

It is important to note that the variants may not contain usize, and might instead be another enum, or struct etc.

```
use std::fmt;
use std::fmt::{Display, Formatter};
use std::error;

#[derive(Debug)]
enum EnumError {
    A,
    B(usize),
    C(usize),
    D,
}

impl error::Error for EnumError {
    fn description(&self) -> &str {
        use EnumError::*;
        match *self {
            A => "A happened",
            B(value) => &*format!("B happened info: {:?}", value),
            C(value) => &*format!("B happened info: {:?}", value),
            D => "D happened",
        }
    }
}

impl Display for EnumError {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
    use std::error::Error;
        write!(f, "{}", self.description())
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

Comment: It's not a duplicate. The answer in the referenced question suggests returning an owned string - that's not an option here because the return type is specified by the trait. I was in the middle of writing an answer to this problem when the question was suddenly closed, it's very frustrating. I edited the question to make the point clear.

Comment: @Malcolm there is simply no way to return a string slice of something created inside a function. I didn't vote for closing but I can't see any solution here except for storing the pre-formatted error string inside the enum itself, which is pretty unwieldy.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev You named both options, this is exactly what I was going to put into my answer. That would be helpful. Directing to a question with an answer which suggests something that can't be done doesn't help at all.

Comment: @Malcolm - looks like you got your wish

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The string you create needs to be owned by something. When you create a local string in the method, you have to transfer its ownership to the caller. But since you have to return `&str`, this is not an option.

The way around it would be to store the string in the struct itself. You can declare the enum value as `B(usize, String)`, put the description there when you create it, and then return it with

```
B(_, ref descr) => descr
```

To be frank, description is not supposed to be a terribly detailed message, it just needs to give a general description of what kind of error this is, this is why it returns `&str`. I didn't see instances of writing any dynamic data into the description in the standard library, usually it's just a static string. `Display` implementation is a different matter though, in there you can be much more verbose.